# Unable to Use RELATED in a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

This is a peculiar issue I'm facing -

Lets say I've a following `Table A` -

| UniqueID | User |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Adam |
| A2 | Dim |
| A3 | Jo |
| A4 | Bill |

and `Table B` -

| UniqueID | RelatedID | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | A2 | Email |
| B2 |  | Email |
| B3 | A3 | Note |
| B4 | C5 | App |

They have an Active Relationship- (`Table A[UniqueID] 1:N Table B[RelatedID]`).

My Slicer is Based of - `TableA[User]` and I wanted a count of only those IDs to show up which had a user in `Table A`

I Made the Following Measure -

```
EmailCount = 
Var _eCount = 
CALCULATETABLE(TableB, TableB[Type] =  "Email" && TableB[RelatedID] <> BLANK() && NOT(ISBLANK(RELATED(TableA[User]))))

Return COUNTROWS(_eCount)
```

I'm getting the following error -

`The column 'TableA[User]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: Hey Davide! Sorry, I can't. Let me know if you've any followup questions.

Comment: Actually, I have something to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EmailCount = 
Var _eCount = 
CALCULATETABLE(TableB, 
FILTER(TableB, 

TableB[Type] =  "Email" && TableB[RelatedID] <> BLANK() && NOT(ISBLANK(RELATED(TableA[User])))))

Return COUNTROWS(_eCount)
```

Explanation:

Your original expands as follows. i.e. ALL() can only cover columns from the same table and there is no Table A to reference. The FILTER in my solution above permits access to the expanded table (in this case both tables)

[image]

Comment: Wow! That worked? How does the `FILTER` function fix this? I know not Using `FILTER` is equal to `FILTER(ALL(TABLE),)` IN CALCULATE/CALCULATETABLE.

Comment: Wait, I see why it is happening. I'll update the answer with an explanation

Comment: Seems like I need to read more and do more. DAX unlike any other language isn't intuitive. Thanks for the explanation, Davide!

Comment: You're not alone. I've been a professional programmer for 20 years and DAX is like nothing else and requires a different way of thinking.